# android- usage of SP

Tags: android

I have doubts regarding the following ones. please clarify it.
1. What is the problem if i set the text of text view in xml file instead of java file(String.xml)? 
2. What is the usage of SP? Give me one example.can anybody helpme.

thanks

Comment: THis explains about the units of android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question: `strings.xml` file is used for storing string resources, especially for the sake of resolving the localization issues. You can store multiple `strings.xml` files inside your project in different folders depending on the localization. This makes translating your application to a different language easier: you just create another `strings.xml` file, translate all the strings and put it inside the corresponding folder. Hope this helps.